# Is it possible to schedule cron job when changes are detected

Tags: cron

I'm setting up my first cron-job and I know I can have it run at specific times every day for example. However, I would really like to only run the command if it detects a change or new file added to a folder. Is that possible with cron? If not, is there another program that would be able to run a command like that (only when it detects changes in a folder). I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might have better luck over on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) as this question isn't really code-based, but the short is that you will need to have some kind of continuously-running job if you want to detect changes when they occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [iWatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html). It watches files or directories for changes, then runs whatever command you specify.